# Getting an error: PHP Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

I just needed a little help from those PHP experts here. I have a little knowledge of PHP. I am getting a `PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types` of this code:

```
$ticket_item_types += array(
    val_paperworkticket => 19,
    val_disposal => 9,
    comment => 22,
    loadtime => 20,
    bbls => 23,
    disposalticketno => 46,
    load_reviewed => 31
);
```

Comment: `$ticket_item_types` Is an array or a string ? Tell us what you expect as result in `$ticket_item_types`

Answer (score 1):

if keys are variables, then, you have to use `$` before variable name, so it must be:

```
$ticket_item_types += array(
    $val_paperworkticket => 19,
    $val_disposal => 9,
    $comment => 22,
    $loadtime => 20,
    $bbls => 23, 
    $disposalticketno => 46,
    $load_reviewed => 31
);
```

if they are strings you have to quote them:

```
$ticket_item_types += array(
    'val_paperworkticket' => 19,
    'val_disposal' => 9,
    'comment' => 22,
    'loadtime' => 20,
    'bbls' => 23,
    'disposalticketno' => 46,
    'load_reviewed' => 31
```

);

Also, take into account that `+` operator with arrays must not be understood as sum operator but `Union` operator

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

[Array Operator (PHP docs)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from your operation +=.

if $ticket_item_types is an array you should use array_push.

Otherwise,

$ticket_item_types = array( val_paperworkticket=>19, val_disposal=>9, comment=>22, loadtime=>20, bbls=>23, disposalticketno=>46, load_reviewed=>31 );

should remove the problem.